# How Do You Clone A WSL Distro?

Tags: linux, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-distributions, wsl2

How would you go about cloning a WSL distro? I have a Debian WSL distribution running under Windows 10 x64 and I would like to clone the distribution without affecting my original one. I have read several documentation over at Microsoft but could not find one explaining this process or if it is *even available* and can be done. Could anyone please explain how and if it is even possible to clone a fresh WSL distribution of Linux?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> How would you go about cloning a WSL distro?

You first must export the WSL distribution you wish to clone.

> 1. `wsl.exe --export OriginalDistributionName FileName`

- **OriginalDistributionName** is the name of the distribution you wish to export.
- **FileName** is the full path to a **tar** file that will be created.

You must now import the distribution you just cloned with the following command:

> 2. `wsl.exe --import ClonedDistributionName InstallLocation FileName`

- **ClonedDistributionName** is the name of the new distribution that will be created.
- **InstallDirectory** is path to the folder the distribution will be installed to.
- **FileName** is the full path file to the **tar** file you created in the previous step.

You can start the cloned distribution by running the following command:

> 3. `wsl --distribution ClonedDistributionName`

Source:

- [Export and Import WSL Linux Distro in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/export-import-wsl-linux-distro-windows-10/)
- [Arguments for managing Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference#arguments-for-managing-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Answer (score 0):

You may intall and manage multiple Linux distros under WSL. This is detailed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#managing-multiple-linux-distributions).

As you say you are seeking to clone a "fresh" distro, the way to do this would be to register the same distro a second time in WSL.

> Reinstalling from the store will install a clean copy of the
> distribution.

**EDIT: Do note that the above approach is for *replacing* your existing distro with a *fresh* one. To clone an *additional* copy, the third approach below (cli) is needed. Note too that like many technologies, WSL has changed and will continue to change, and you should always check the documentation for the version you are using.**

You may also [sideload a custom distro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/build-custom-distro), which may be a way to achieve more control over the naming of your distros and hence register similar distros under the name of your choice.

And you may use the [cli](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference) to export and import copies of your distros:

> [image]